# TextBox data is cut off when exporting to Excel 2010 from SSRS 2008

Tags: excel, reporting-services, formatting, ssrs-2008, export-to-excel

I have an SSRS 2008 report that displays the TextBox and it's content correctly in SSRS but when I try to export it to Excel 2010 the data is cut off as seen below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/g87oh.jpg

I made sure that the CanGrow property for this textbox is set to True:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LyUV9.png

Comment: what version of excel are you opening the export in... I ask because In most cases excel does not handle line breaks within a cell very gracefully and it is much worse in older versions of excel

Comment: I'm using Excel 2010

Comment: try holding ctrl and scrolling up and down this will increase and decrease the zoom. if you see the size of the font changing but not changing in proportion to the size of the cell then you have your answer. Just another pitfall of exporting to excel